# jquery ui datepicker setDate not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a very simple setup which is surprisingly not working:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="08/03/2016" class="datepicker" />
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({
       setDate: "08/03/2016"
   });
});
```

No matter if having input-value set or not, its always showing up October 2015 on open. **Why so?**

Comment: Which Datepicker library are you using ? Have you try a different date format, like 2016-03-08 ?

Comment: Can you create a sample on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the datepicker first:

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    $('.datepicker').datepicker("setDate",  "08/03/2016");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n3Lapbhn/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", "08/03/2016" );
```

Its a method call and not the option while initializing it.